# convergence of matrix exponential as matrix converges entrywisely

Tags: matrices, convergence-divergence, matrix-exponential

I wonder that whether $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{A_n}=e^A$ or not, if the matrix $A_n$ converges to $A$ entrywise. if not, does the convergence holds under some manner of convergence for $A_n\rightarrow A$?

Comment: Because all norms on finite dimensional spaces are equivalent, saying that $A_n$ converges pointwise is the same as saying that $A_n$ converges with respect to any matrix norm. With this in mind, your question amounts to asking whether the matrix exponential function is continuous (which it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By continuity of norm, for $n$ large enough, we have $\left \|A_n \right \| \leq 1+\left \|A \right \|$.
One can show by induction that
$$\left \| A^k-A_n^k \right \| \leq \left \|A-A_n \right \| \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\left \|A \right \|^i \left \|A_n \right \|^{k-1-i} \leq k \left \|A-A_n \right \| (1+\left \|A \right \|)^k. $$
By definition, one has
$$\left \| e^A-e^{A_n} \right \| = \left \| \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}(A^k-A_n^k) \right \| \leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k}{k!}  \left \|A-A_n \right \| (1+\left \|A \right \|)^k \leq \left \|A-A_n \right \|(1+\left \|A \right \|)e^{1+\left \|A \right \|},$$
which proves that $e^{A_n}  \rightarrow e^{A}$ if $A_{n}  \rightarrow A$.

Comment: Last line should say $e^{A}$ instead of $A$.